# How to use chai's expect in nightwatch.js tests

Tags: chai, nightwatch.js

I do integration tests with nightwatch. Some UI automation, which works fine. In the end I want to check using a Rest API, if the results of the UI operations are right. I try to use chai there, as chai is inbuild into nightwatch. Out of the box nightwatch only supports expect.element('#element')..., but I need expect(true).to.be.true style.

This is (part) of my test file:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');

module.exports = {
    'Add Rules (Tester 1)' : browser => {
         ... some tests
    }
    after: browser => {
        let username = 'username';
        let password = 'xxxxxxxx';

        fetchRulesFromJira({ browser, username, password }).then(rules => {
            expect(rules.length).to.equal(2);
            browser.end();
        });
    }
};
```

If the expect fails the output is

> (node:3594) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected 3 to equal 2

Somehow useful but not nice. If the test succeeds then there is no output.

How can I make nightwatch.js print the results, or any other way to have a more standard output of test results?

Comment: You should return the promise :
`return fetchRulesFromJira({ browser, username, password }).then(....);`

Comment: That doesn't do it unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, it would be nice if the `expect` assertions could be used for more than just elements. The workaround I use for this instead is `browser.verify.ok()` and then I just add a message that describes what the test is actually doing so that when I look at the results I can see what test it was. In your case it would be something like this:

```
browser.verify.ok(rules.length === 2, 'there are 2 rules');
```

In the console you will see a message like this:

```
Passed [ok]: there are 2 rules
```

Although, I don't think the above approach will handle your promise rejection issue at all. You could just put a `catch` after the `then` and that will fix your issue with the unhandled promise rejection. This is the right way to handle rejected promises.

```
fetchRulesFromJira({ browser, username, password }).then(rules => {
        expect(rules.length).to.equal(2);
        browser.end();
    })
    .catch(err => {
       browser.assert.fail(err);
    });
```

Also, after looking at your code again I have one last thing to mention. You are trying to do an assertion in an `after` method. This will run after all the tests have completed. Typically you would use the `after` function for some kind of cleanup or teardown. I'm still new to nightwatch but I don't think it is best practice to put assertions in there. Also, I'm not entirely sure they even work in the `before[Each]` or `after[Each]` functions. If you put that assertion inside a test function you should start seeing the output in the console.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution ist to encapsulate the `expect` in try/catch and invoke an error with nightwatch.

```
const { expect } = require('chai');

module.exports = {
    'Add Rules (Tester 1)' : browser => {
         ... some tests
    }
    after: browser => {
        let username = 'username';
        let password = 'xxxxxxxx';

        fetchRulesFromJira({ browser, username, password }).then(rules => {
            try {
                expect(rules.length).to.equal(2);
            } catch(error) {
                browser.assert.fail(error);
            }

            browser.end();
        });
    }
};
```

That doesn't look perfect, but the output is quite ok.